# Entity Framework v5.0 Exception 'From' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped

Tags: sql, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

I use EntityFrameWork v5.0, EntityDataSource control.

In code I set SQL query, but when I open page after compilation I get exception. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
entryListDs.CommandParameters.Add(new Parameter("subId", DbType.Int32, Common.CurrentUserID.ToString()));
entryListDs.CommandParameters.Add(new Parameter("typeId", DbType.Int32, ((int)MessageType.Wall).ToString()));

entryListDs.CommandText = @"SELECT 
m.ID,
m.To,
m.Subject,
m.BodyHtml,
m.CreationDate,
m.New,
m.TypeID
FROM 
message AS m
JOIN subscription AS s
ON m.From = s.ObjectID
WHERE s.SubscriberID = @subId and m.TypeID = @typeId
ORDER BY m.CreationDate DESC";
```

Exeption when I open page:

**'From' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped. Near line 12, column 6.**

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.EntitySqlException: 'From' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped. Near line 12, column 6.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[EntitySqlException: 'From' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped. Near line 12, column 6.]
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.MapUnescapedIdentifier(String symbol) +8073331
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.MapIdentifierOrKeyword(String symbol) +57
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.Accept_83() +36
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.yylex() +386
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.yylex() +16
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.yyparse() +132
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.internalParseEntryPoint() +101
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.Parse(String query) +148
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlQuery.Parse(String commandText, ParserOptions parserOptions) +41
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlQuery.CompileCommon(String commandText, Perspective perspective, ParserOptions parserOptions, Func`3 compilationFunction) +84
   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlQuery.CompileQueryCommandLambda(String queryCommandText, Perspective perspective, ParserOptions parserOptions, IEnumerable`1 parameters, IEnumerable`1 variables) +100
   System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState.Parse() +8608663
   System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState.GetResultType() +4
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.GetResultType() +58
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceQueryBuilder`1.BuildBasicQuery(ObjectContext context, Boolean computeCount) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelectTyped(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Creator qbConstructor) +355
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +606
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +102
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use keywords or special symbols in column names, then brackets are required. Just put column name in square brackets:

```
ON m.[From] = s.ObjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

It says right there in your Exception: `From is a reserved keyword`.

In your query you have `ON m.From = s.ObjectID`. You need to rename your `From` column to something else.